# Looking for a way to have LaTeX source code and its real-time rendering in side-by-side Emacs windows

Tags: org-mode, latex, auctex, tex

I am looking for a way to use Emacs as a LaTeX editor that couples a persistent LaTeX source window with an adjacent real-time rendered view of the LaTeX-encoded content, similar to what is available at [several StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) (e.g. see [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

The only difference between what I'm hoping to find and what these StackExchange sites support is that I would like to have the source code and the corresponding real-time-rendered<sup>1</sup> output living in *side-by-side* Emacs windows (i.e. the arrangement of windows one gets by running `C-x 3`, aka `M-x split-window-right`), while in the SE sites the source code area is placed *above* the preview area.

I have looked (very superficially!) at various TeX/LaTeX rendering tools for Emacs (e.g. [TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html), [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html), [AUCTEX](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/img/preview-screenshot.png)), but none are/do quite<sup>2</sup> what I want.

It could be that, contrary to my first impressions, I may be able to do what I want to do with one of the tools mentioned above.  If so, please point me to a suitable how-to guide.

Alternatively, is there some *other* tool, one that I have not yet explored, that can do what I'm after?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Here, by "rendered" I mean the fully typeset output one gets if one runs `latex path/to/mypaper.tex; dvipdf path/to/mypaper.dvi`.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> My main problem with TeXmacs is that it looks to me like it tries to be a point-clicky completely WYSIWYG MS Word-like equation editor.  I.e. their aim seems to be to keep the TeX/LaTeX out-of-sight.  I'm sure there are people who like this way of doing things, but I absolutely detest it, to put it mildly.  My problem with both org-mode and AUCTEX is that they display the rendered LaTeX "inline", in a way that hides, at least temporarily, the source code.  In other words, one can somehow toggle between the source view and the rendered view.  I don't find this approach as awful as I find TeXmacs's, but still I find it far less desirable than the approach I described in my post.</sup>

Comment: Do you know latex-preview-pane? (available on melpa)

Comment: @gigiair: Thank you!!!  `latex-preview-pane` is great!  The interaction with it not quite as fluid as the interaction with SE's MathJax interface, but it is definitely adequate for my purposes.  I would be glad to accept your proposal as the answer to my question, if you post it as such.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190882/what-is-the-best-side-by-side-preview-method-for-emacs24-auctex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`latex-preview-pane` on `melpa` can do that.

You can enable it in a file being edited with AUCTeX by `M-x latex-preview-pane RET` or for any LaTeX file opened in this mode by placing

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'latex-preview-pane-mode)
```

in your Emacs initialization file.

[image: latex-preview-pane]